# ajax not calling php, php works when called directly

Tags: php, html, ajax

I know this has been answered before, but I still can't seem to find a solution that works for me. I have a form submission that is not working with the ajax call. I'm pretty sure its not the HTML or PHP, because If i execute the php directly, everything works fine. when going through ajax however, I get the console log messages, and the success block is executed, but I never get an email. any help would be much appreciated

my java script function

```
$('#ajax-contact').submit(function(event){

    console.log(event)
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstname = $('#fname');
    var lastname = $('#lname');
    var subject = $('#subject');
    var body = $('#body');

    console.log(firstname);
    console.log(lastname);
    console.log(subject);
    console.log(body);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        URL: "send_mail.php",
        data: "firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body,
        success: function(){
            $("#ajax-contact").trigger("reset");
             window.alert("Message Successfully Sent");
        }
    });
});
```

and the php file

```
<?php

$to = "xxxxxxx";
$subject  = $_POST["subject"];
$body = "Message from ".$_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"]." \r\n ".$_POST['body'];
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
echo('Email successfully sent!');
return("success");
} else {
echo('Error Failed...');
return("Error");
}

?>
```

Comment: should be `url` not `URL`

Comment: next time check the developer tools in your browser to see if its even making a network request.

Comment: You need to change to json data and no url query content its a bad practice.

Comment: yeah Its making the network request, and like I said in the post, It is returning the success block message so I have to think its executing without anything really bad happening

Comment: You need to encode the `data` parameters properly in case they contain special characters. The best way to do that is to pass an object, which jQuery will encode automatically. If not, you need to call `encodeURIComponent(body)`.

Comment: @Ulises PHP won't automatically decode JSON, it only knows about `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`. As I said above, it's best to pass an object to `$.ajax`, jQuery will then send it as proper URL-encoded post data.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `method:` option was added in 1.9.0, before that it was called `type:`.

Comment: If the script is executing successfully, but you're not getting any email, it could be getting blocked by a spam filter somewhere. Check the mail logs on your server to see if the mail is being sent.

Comment: thanks for the help @Barmar ..... I went away from that and called the serialize method on the form. seems to be working well now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data needs to be encoded properly in case it contains special characters that affect parsing it (this is especially likely in the `body` parameter). Either use the `serialize()` method to get all the inputs from the form:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

or pass an object, which jQuery will serialize automatically:

```
data: { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, subject: subject, body: body},
```

In ES6 you can simplify that to:

```
data: {firstname, lastname, subject, body},
```